# Truffle Migration Error Avalanche C Chain

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, evm, avalanche

I am using Truffle suite in a project in production, but I am sick of dealing with this error I feel shouldn't even be happening, and maybe its because of something that Avalanche has set on their side, but I am hoping for some clarity here.

I keep getting presented with this error when running migrations, it happens at entirely random intervals (mid script after 4 successful txs, while also happening immidiately when the script is run). This error happens every migration, run of a script, or anything targeting C-Chain (mainnet). Even a script calling 'read-only' functions...

> Error: Unhandled error. ({ code: -32000, message: 'cannot query unfinalized data' })
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
> at Web3ProviderEngine.emit (node:events:379:17)

I have asked this question already in the Avalanche dev discord chat, and I was informed verbatim that:

> That error message is returned when someone specifies a height that is > than the last accepted block height.

Not only this, but allegedly this same check is present on fuji testnet, and i NEVER EVER EVER have this issue on fuji testnet...

Since I am using truffle's contract abstractions, I am not aware how I could be 'specifying' anything, in fact I added the Avalanche recommended gas levels to the truffle-config, which did not help at all. There is no mention of this error in truffle docs anywhere or this concept from what i can find. Not as it relates to errors in migrations or with the truffle contracts package etc...

For those that will give me the answer of 'use hardhat bro', I HAVE used hardhat and i loathe it. Want to spend time writing contracts not fiddling with plug ins. Truffles abi's make keeping track of projects with many contracts and moving addresses a breeze, which is why I am trying to make the most of truffle suite, albeit the docs leaving something to be desired, especially with drizzle....

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to determining the finality of blocks on Avalanche C-Chain. You can also try setting the `allow-unfinalized-queries` config on your node client to `true` (default is `false`). This setting allows queries for unfinalized (not yet accepted) blocks/transactions.

See:

https://docs.avax.network/quickstart/integrate-exchange-with-avalanche

http://www.beiion.com/ava/build/references/avalanchego-config-flags/index.html

Comment: This looks like its for setting this boolean on the AvalancheGo client. This is not the issue, seems like a block polling issue if anything, increasing polling interval in chain config does not fix. To clarify I am using a script file within the context of truffle. So any and all 'chain configs' go into the truffle-config.js. I still appreciate the help. But if its a thing that I need to change it must be in truffle, as thats what gives me my contract abstractions and provider/wallets etc.